# Node fetch request using axios returns gibberish data as response

Tags: node.js, api, axios

I am a beginner in node and I am trying to consume an API,but response returns gibberish data.I have tested the API routes and I am sure the problem is my request but I clearly cannot tell where.I think I am making an obvious mistake but it is hard to tell.
Here is the function to generate the token

```
const generateToken = async (req, res, next) => {
  const secret = proces.env.MPESA_CONSUMER_SECRET;
  const consumer = process.env.MPESA_CONSUMER_KEY;

  const auth = new Buffer.from(`${consumer}:${secret}`).toString("base64");
  await axios
    .get(
      "https://sandbox.safaricom.co.ke/oauth/v1/generate?grant_type=client_credentials",
      {
        headers: {
          authorization: `Basic ${auth}`,
        },
      }
    )
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      // token = response.data.access_token;
      next();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      //res.status(400).json(err.message)
    });
};
app.get("/token", (req, res) => {
  generateToken();
});
```

the response I get after console.log is this

```
data: '\x1F�\b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00���R@\x02J��ɩ���%�٩yJV\n' +
    'J��.�EU�\x1E��Y�N)%IQ\x01\x05\x16���&N�f\x01J:�zS+\n' +
    '2�R��3�:�M--��\n' +
    'j�,\x00�H��q\x00\x00\x00'
}
```

Anyhelp to even help me understand where the problem could be will be highly apprecited.

Comment: Your question says `node fetch`, but you are using `axios`. I assumed that you are using `node-fetch` module

Comment: Try adding `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` to `headers`

Comment: I have tried adding Content-Type but still not fixed.

Comment: Duplicate of the many many other questions about axios in the last 13 days. [Bug report](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5298). Downgrade to 1.1.3 and wait for the fix to be released.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading to Axios version 1.1.3 worked for me

Comment: Upgraded Axios and works now. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1):

### In v1.2.1 fixed this error.

Try it after install axios(v1.2.1) again

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an older version of axios v1.2.1 should fix the issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).